# Module %s has open descendants or linked modules. can not reload

Tags: delphi, internationalization, delphi-6

I am adding a language to my project for Arabic. When i update the resource Dlls, i am getting the following error in one of the base form from which all other forms were inherited.

I tried setting the OldCreateOrder to false for all the forms, but still the error persists. I have tried searching on the net for this kind of error, but no luck....

Does any one know about this error?? BTW i am using Delphi 6 Enterprise version.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I made a workaround and was able to create a resource DLL using the external translation manager. However, when i place the resource dll and load it, i wasn't able to see any string. All the constants declared using the reourcestring are blank.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have solved the problem.

I couldn't able to find out the reason for the failure of the IDE to compile my project, but the external translation manager helped.

I forgot to add the DRC file to the translation manager. As a result, my resourcestrings were not loaded automatically.

For newbies who want to port the application to different languages,

1. Open the external translation manager from the Delphi6\Bin folder.
2. Select a language in the environment tab and in the files tab, select all the files that were used in the project. (Don't forget the DRC files)
3. Run the updaters and save the project file with the extension of the language selected.
4. Select the strings that need to be translated and add them to repository.
5. Translate the strings required.
6. Add the project created using the ETM to the project group and compile.
7. The resource dll file name should match the exe name, but the extension should be of the language. like xxxx.ARQ for arabic Qatar.

Thanks every 1