# How to debug or fix "Module has open descendants or linked modules" error?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

I've had this long time problem that I can't view as text the main form for a project I inherited. Even if no other forms are open.

How can I debug the cause of this error message? What options do I have to fix it?

I found one related newsgroup post http://embarcadero.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.ide/200906/0906193960.html but this only addresses the form inheritance cause, and doesn't explain anything about linked modules. I don't believe I'm using form inheritance.

I do have a DM (data module) for the project, and the form does load a couple of images from the dm through properties of a TTreeView on the form--does having a data module automatically mean I can never view as text a form in Delphi (aside from viewing the form as text in notepad)? It doesn't seem to matter whether my DM is open or closed in the IDE.

I also found one SO question with a related title ([Module %s has open descendants or linked modules. can not reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382299/module-s-has-open-descendants-or-linked-modules-can-not-reload)) but the question itself and it's answer is not particularly relevant.

Comment: Couldn't you make a minimal reproduction? Indeed if you did so I predict you'd solve the problem yourself. As you cutdown the code and components you'd find that the problem disappears. The last thing you stripped away is thus the key. This is an essential debugging skill to learn. Isolate the problem.

Comment: I'll give making a minimal reproduction a try. But I'd still like to understand what the error means because I have as of yet been unsuccessful in finding any official documentation about this error ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This is sometimes caused by a form that inherits from another form in your project (or the gallery) (known as Visual Form Inheritance in the documentation, IIRC). The IDE doesn't know how to find the base class for the form; it needs that opened before the descendant form. For instance, this can cause the same error if the unit containing `TMyBaseForm` isn't opened first in the IDE, particularly if the base (ancestor) unit is not included in the project first:

```
unit SpecialForm;

interface

uses
  Forms, { all the other usual stuff }, BaseForm;

type
  TMySpecialForm = class(TMyBaseForm)
  private

  public

  end;
```

You can tell if this is the case by looking at your form's class declaration - if it descends from anything other than `TForm`, this is probably the cause of the error.

(Another instance of it happening is often when using a datamodule, because the base `TDataModule` .DFM isn't available. Attempting to view the datamodule .DFM as text will cause this error every time; the solution is to close your project and use an external editor such as Notepad or Notepad++ to edit the .dfm for your datamodule.)

Comment: Hmm...I was able to verify my form extends TForm directly, there's no base class in between, and Forms is is definitely in the uses clause...so I'm still leaning toward suspecting inheritance insn't the cause in my case. Any pointers as far as the "linked modules" being a possible cause of this error?

Comment: No, sorry. This is the only reason I've ever encountered for the problem (which is why I wrote "sometimes" rather than "the cause is"). Are you missing a line in the project file (Project->View Source) for the unit in question? It should be something along the lines of `uses Forms, Unit4 in 'Unit4.pas' {Form4};` - note the part in `{}` at the end. Is that present for the form you're having problems with? (It would be *so* much easier if you posted some code or relevant details that we could see, rather than having to speculate on what you might or might not have.)

Comment: Also, if you open the .dfm in question from Notepad, what does the first line in that .dfm say? It should be `object Form4: TForm4` (replacing `Form4` in both cases with your form's name and class, of course).

Comment: Actually the issue is not that the base can't be found. Rather that the IDE already has the base open. And the descendent open. The error is telling you that you cannot modify the base because a descendent is open.

Comment: @David: Actually, no. The IDE is confused, because it *thinks* you have it open but it isn't in fact open. (If it were, you could find it in an editor tab and close it, and you can't.) As I said, I've experienced this before (in fact, just a few minutes ago with a datamodule that clearly has no ancestor loaded in the IDE).

Comment: My comment was based on what you say in your answer: *This is sometimes caused by a form that inherits from another form in your project (or the gallery) (known as Visual Form Inheritance in the documentation, IIRC). The IDE doesn't know how to find the base class for the form.*

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue occasionally, perhaps when I've used Frames, but my latest instance didn't involve Frames nor Data Modules nor inherited forms.

After an enormous amount of work creating a copy of the form (which copy didn't have the problem) and renaming the original unit and the form itself (which initially seemed to solve the problem), it turned out to be a live binding between forms.

Specifically, in my FMX application Form A has an options page with a TSpinBox that allows the user to set the minimum value for a TTrackBar on Form B (which was the form giving me grief).  So the TSpinBox.Value was set to update the TTrackBar.Min field by means of a live binding.  Closing Form A, or removing that live binding (and replacing it with an event handler to do the same thing) solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to call upon the answer of Phillip J. Rayment and ADD that you don't have to have live binding to have this problem occur. It's sufficient to have custom control (class) of which you have an instance in another form. Then the RLink32 problem can appear and won't be solved until you close the form where you have the instance. The problem I experienced gave the following messages: 
-`RLink32 (during building)`
-Access violation in module designide160.bpl` (if I made a modification to the problematic form)
-The module has open descendants or linked modules” error (if I tried to 'View as Form')